# javacpp-opencv drawContours produce different result than in python?

Tags: opencv, javacpp

javacpp-opencv drawContours produce wrong result than in python.

Here is the code in java to use `drawContours` function:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Mat im = imread("7KXY.png");
    cvtColor(im, im, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(im,im, 230, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    MatVector contours = new MatVector();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    findContours(im, contours,hierarchy,RETR_TREE  ,CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    im = new Mat(im.rows(),im.cols(),CV_8UC1);
    drawContours(im, contours, -1, new Scalar(255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 2, new Point(0,0));
    imwrite( "ccc.jpg", im);
}
```

result
[image]

Here is identical python code:

```
im = cv2.imread(r'7KXY.png')
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh,im = cv2.threshold(im, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_TREE , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

im = np.zeros(im.shape).astype(dtype='uint8')
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (255), 1,8, hierarchy, 2,(0,0))
cv2.imwrite(r"asd.jpg",im)
```

result [image]

maven pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The original picture[image]

Comment: Try: `im = Mat.zeros(im.rows(), im.cols(), CV_8UC1);`

Comment: tried  that ,still didn't work.@Silencer金

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: ```Mat im = imread("7KXY.png");
cvtColor(im, im, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(im,im, 230, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
MatVector contours = new MatVector();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
findContours(im, contours,hierarchy,RETR_TREE  ,CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
//im = new Mat(im.rows(),im.cols(),CV_8UC1);
Mat imxx = Mat.zeros(im.rows(), im.cols(), CV_8UC1).asMat();
drawContours(imxx, contours, -1, new Scalar(255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 2, new Point(0,0));
imwrite( "ccc.jpg", imxx);``` Result is a complete black image @Silencer金

Comment: Are you sure that you are using similar version of OpenCV across Java and Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `new Scalar(255)` creates an array of Scalar objects with undefined color:

- http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.Scalar.html#Scalar-long-

We need to call `new Scalar(255.0)` to have it do what is needed here:

- http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.Scalar.html#Scalar-double-

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OpenCV 4.0.0 for Python 3.6 | Java 11.

This is my Java test code and result:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); 

    Mat im = Imgcodecs.imread("7KXY.jpg");
    Imgproc.cvtColor(im, im, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(im,im, 230, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(im, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    im = Mat.zeros(im.rows(), im.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

    Imgproc.drawContours(im, contours, -1, new Scalar(255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 2, new Point(0,0));
    Imgcodecs.imwrite( "dst.jpg", im);
}
```

[image]  [image]